# Google+ signin signs user out

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am experiencing a problem when a user is logged in to more than one Google account.

My application has a login page with a Google+ signin button.

The user clicks the button and authorises the application.

The signinCallback is fired correctly. The app then renders a new page, which  has a hidden signin button (to allow the user to sign out). When this page is rendered, the signinCallback is fired again, but with "user_signed_out" in the error field. The status contains:

```
google_logged_in: true
method: null
signed_in: false
```

I don't see a way of handling this error.

Anybody else experienced this issue?

Comment: I am experiencing this issue as well. I have no idea what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not revoking the access token you requested. If youre using javascript use this. Revoking the access token will allow you to request another token for other user.

```
        var revokeUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' + access_token;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: revokeUrl,
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(nullResponse) {
                //do logout call back here

            },
            error: function(e) {
               console.log(e);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that although I have included *A* signin button on both pages, it is not *the same* signin button. It seems that when a user initially signed in, that state is saved in the signin button *on that page*. So when the app navigates away from the page with that signin button, strange things happen. Another issue I have faced as a result of the same issue is that the user is unable to sign out.

Answer (score 0):

Add another button for sing out. Than on click just call

```
gapi.auth.signOut();
```

It can be any button, [look here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/sign-out).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same problem on my test site when i was doing the following

testsite.com

however when i changed it to www.testsite.com it worked perfectly and flawlessly.

Please make sure that you guys have the proper sub domain.